# 3G modem is getting disconnected and not showing anymore in network manager icon

Tags: network-manager, modem, 3g

I am using a BSNL 3G modem in India. I've noticed that, after using it for a time, internet is getting disconnected and it is disappearing from network manager icon. In order to connect again, modem must be removed and re-inserted. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open 'Network Tools".
2. Select 'Ping' tab.
3. Type www.google.com for the network address.
4. Select 'Unlimited requests'
5. Finally click PING!

Leave the window alone, and continue your work. This will keep your Internet connection busy, so the service provider (Airtel) can't drop your connection.

Comment: keep pinging consumes network traffic. BTW connection drop thing happens to me while downloading also.

Answer (score 0):

Type the **ping www.bing.com -s 1** in the terminal and press enter after you are connected to the Internet. 
This will keep your Internet Service Provider busy, so they can't drop your connection.
Make sure you have updated your OS to gain the best hardware support for your USB modem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it disappears from network manager applet.

Do disable/enable mobile broadband from network applet.

Most of the time it works for me.